# MS Access Query - Count Repeat of first instnace in a date range

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in Access with Account Numbers and Date and Time. I can count the repeat occurrences of the account numbers, but I want to do so within a 7 day range and without “double counting”. Only counting the immedately following record as a repeat of the previous.

Current data:

http://postimg.org/image/q4m62fh9z/

What I want:

http://postimg.org/image/jn6auf7vp/

Comment: My images never show, can an admin help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read the tour and faq. Specifically, you should probably edit your question and add the required sample as text, not pictures.